# Difference influxdb and influxb_client libraries

Tags: python, influxdb

I'm kind of new to influx, and I'm a bit confused by the presence of two different libraries for interacting with influxDB via python: [`influxdb`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) and [`influxdb_client`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python).

What are the differences between the two? Which one should I use?